# template constructor in non template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class definition:

```
class image {

public:

  template <class T> image(int w, int h);
  virtual ~image();

  void clear();
};

template <class T> image::image(int w, int h) {
  ...
  ...
}
```

The constructor is defined in the same header file. Now, how do I instantiate an object of this class?

I tried this

```
image a<float>(128, 128);
```

but got the following error

```
error: expected initializer before '<' token
image a<float>(128, 128);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't use leading double underscore in your own symbols, [they are reserved in all scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Yes but both cases in the duplicates the answer is no but in this case it is invokable if you tweak the parameters to use __T so it can be deduced.

Comment: Your methods are not `public`.

Comment: So, the only way is to tweak an argument into the ctor of type `T`?